How to tell which extension opened a Chrome tab
I have about 50+ Chrome extensions running and one is currently misbehaving. It opens copies of currently open windows including all tabs. Once I came back to my computer to find over 1000 tabs open when I normally only have about 100.
Is there any way to determine which extension has opened a certain tab so I can figure out what's causing this issue?

The only retroactive method I see is to check the logs in chrome://safe-browsing/.
